# React Native Function Outside Class Pass Item to Function Inside

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I have a Flatlist inside my default component, I want to perform an on item click with Touchables, when the item is touched it should get one of its items called "Source" and pass it to another function called "deleteImage".
Now the problem is that my RenderItem (Which is called ItemAdImages) is outside the main component but the deleteImage is inside the component so it can't pass "Source" to deleteImage.
my renderItem Code:

```
   Export Default Class ... Extends Component{
     render(){

return(

    <SafeAreaView style={{
                            marginBottom: 10, flex: 1,
                            alignContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.avatarsArray}
                                renderItem={({item}) => <ItemAdImages
                                    source={item.source}
                                    data={item.data}
                                />}
                                numColumns={3}
                                keyExtractor={(item) => item.data}
                                contentContainerStyle={{margin: 0}}
                                extraData={this.state.itemImagesListRefresh}
                            />
                        </SafeAreaView>


             )//return
            }//render


    deleteImage(imageSource){

            console.log("image source is = " + imageSource)

            for(let i = 0; i < this.state.avatarsArray.length; i++){
                if (this.state.avatarsArray[i]['source'] === imageSource){
                    this.state.avatarsArray.splice(i, 1);
                    this.setState({itemImagesListRefresh: !this.state.itemImagesListRefresh})
                    console.log(this.state.avatarsArray)
                }
                else {
                    console.log(this.state.avatarsArray[i] + " Not It")
                }
            }

        }//deleteImage

     }//main component
```

**and my renderItem function outside main component:**

```
function ItemAdImages({source, data, id, state}) {

    return (

        <Container style={{height: 45, width: 90, backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        margin: 10}}>
            <Content>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteImage(source)}>
                    <View >
                        <Image
                            //source= {{uri: "content://media/external/images/media/29"}}
                            source= {{uri: source}}
                            //source= {{uri : this.state.avatarsArray[0].source}}
                            //source= {{uri : this.state.avatarsArray[0].source}}
                            style={{width: 90, height: 45,
                                backgroundColor: '#FF9900'}} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Content>
        </Container>

    ) }
```

**The error is :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the deleteimage function as a parameter to the item component

```
 renderItem={({item}) => <ItemAdImages
                                    source={item.source}
                                    data={item.data}
                                    deleteImage={this.deleteImage}
                                />}
```

And access it just like any other prop

function ItemAdImages({source, data, id, state, deleteImage}) {

```
return (

    <Container style={{height: 45, width: 90, backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
    margin: 10}}>
        <Content>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteImage(source)}>
                <View >
                    <Image
                        //source= {{uri: "content://media/external/images/media/29"}}
                        source= {{uri: source}}
                        //source= {{uri : this.state.avatarsArray[0].source}}
                        //source= {{uri : this.state.avatarsArray[0].source}}
                        style={{width: 90, height: 45,
                            backgroundColor: '#FF9900'}} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Content>
    </Container>

) }
```

Comment: Oh My Godddd You are a life saver! I've been stuck on this error for 3 days and your solution absolutely works! Thanks man, Thank you very much

Comment: This works thanks... but is it ok to use this for large list or large data?

Comment: @CrackerKSR yes it should work fine